# Transform Scale & Background Color On Hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something that's fairly straightforward and I've been looking through many examples but can't seem to get this to work as I expect. What I am trying to do if have an image that on hover will scale(1.1) and then add a background-color also. As you can see I have no problem with selecting the image within the image-holder that I created and scaling this on hover but then when I try to add the overlay to this and get that to add on hover it doesn't work. I attached the code below

```
<div class="image-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn2.artbees.net/jupiter5/orthosie/wp-content/uploads/sites/51/bfi_thumb/portfolio-feature-07-msnw0wxnyitxdmhlcfsb7elky0xl4drzq8bc37266o.jpg" width="300" height="200">
    <div class="image-overlay"></div>
</div>

.image-holder {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.image-holder:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
.image-overlay:hover > img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a tint over the image or a padding surrounding the image?

Comment: @bdkopen Tint over the image. Ideally I am going to be using rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); but was trying to get any overlay to work at the moment

Comment: @bdkopen. Thanks again I ended up getting it with your suggestion. I used the same idea of using a pseudo class but in the inverse way as you have in the demo.

Comment: Answer your own question so others can see the final product. Codepen link: https://codepen.io/jr/pen/rliKq